# How do I set the instance count of a Elastic Beanstalk environment to 0?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In other words I would like to temporarily turn off an environment (and its associated billing costs) but not delete it entirely.

It seems if I set the [Configuration > Web Tier > Scaling > Minimum instance count] to 0 along with the related "Maximum instance count", AWS rejects those settings as invalid. Ditto for questionable values like 0.1.

Any ideas for temporarily taking an Elastic Beanstalk environment out of service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Find and select the [EC2 Autoscaling Group](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?#AutoScalingGroups:) for the Elastic Beanstalk environment in the AWS Console. It should be named something like `awseb-e-*-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-*`.
- Press the "Edit" button. Change the "Desired capacity" to 0.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by defining time periods in your environment.

from your Elastic Load blanancer dashboard navigate through: Configuration -> Capacity -> Time-based scaling -> Scheduled actions.

You may choose to use multiple scheduled actions to start and stop your environment.

i.e. One to start your environment and another to stop it, or scale out during high load periods and back in after.

In the background, Elastic Beanstalk will terminate and recreate the EC2. This means you'll lose any data on the instances local storage.

[image: shows the Scheduled actions screen in aws]

I have used this to turn my environments off when they are no longer needed. For example, I have a workload that crawls looking for new content; and I pause this crawling after it has once completed. I also use this feature to spin down my nonproduction environments outside of working hours.

I prefer this method to others as it is supported by both single instance and load-balanced environments.

Answer (score 2):

How about `eb scale 0` using the Elastic Beanstalk CLI tools?

Comment: This didn't work for me at first because my app was set to rolling updates and I got an error.  If your app is configured to update all at once, then this works.

Comment: This used to work for me, but now I find it's not. Due to the rolling update configuration that @gaefan mentions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible. I any case, you would still have a load balancer in front for which you pay, so you're not really reducing the costs for this environment.

It makes more sense to delete the environment completely create a script that will deploy a version from your application versions to a new environment.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking today. You can actually in beanstalk set Min and Max capacity to 0 and it will work as expected.